# Run an XSLT transformation on TeamCity

Tags: xslt, teamcity

Is there any *built-in* way to run an XSLT transformation on TeamCity? Preferably, as a build step. As I have not found anything in the docs so far, I'm not too confident about that feature, however, maybe somebody already integrated an XSLT transformation in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, teamcity doesn't have an XSLT trasform runner. However you could use below powershell script to transform.

```
$xslt = new-object system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform
$xslt.load('D:\SampleTransform.xsl')
$xslt.Transform('D:\Input.xml', 'D:\Output.xml')
```

Comment: This answer is only usable on Windows environments.  TeamCity is used on Linux and other Unix systems as well.

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity does not have dedicated XSLT transformation runner.

But using the Ant runner with "Build file content" option you can configure required transformation from the UI. Just provide a content like this:

```
 <project default="MyXSLT">
  <target name="MyXSLT">
    <xslt in="MyInput.xml" 
      out="MyOutput.xml"
      style="MyTransform.xslt">
    </xslt>
  </target>
</project>
```

You can even make this step re-usable by creating meta-runner. See [this documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Meta-Runner) for details

Answer (score 0):

Try the [xslt runner](http://naiduv.github.io/Teamcity-XSLT-build-runner-plugin/)

It is a simple runner, like command line, but it comes bundled with msxsl.exe. So no need to install it on the agent.